# WordPress current user

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't get currently logged in user. In localhost root folder i have wordpress directory and api directory. From api/index.php file i'm trying to get logged in user but it's not working.

api/index.php

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require '../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php';

global $current_user;
var_dump($current_user);
```

Result:

```
object(WP_User)[2369]
  public 'data' => null
  public 'ID' => int 0
  public 'caps' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'cap_key' => null
  public 'roles' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'allcaps' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'filter' => null
```

I tried also:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require '../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php';

var_dump(wp_login('admin', 'admin'));
global $current_user;
var_dump($current_user);
```

Result:

```
boolean true
object(WP_User)[2369]
  public 'data' => null
  public 'ID' => int 0
  public 'caps' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'cap_key' => null
  public 'roles' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'allcaps' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'filter' => null
```

I'm tried to use root cookie plugin, but it's not working.
Register globals are off in php.ini

Does anyone have idea what might be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

Replicated the problem in a local environment. I suspect your require path isn't correct. What worked for me was the following:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp-blog-header.php');

global $current_user;
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($current_user);
echo '</pre>';
```

You should use the following function to get the current user.

```
wp_get_current_user();
```

If you want to access attributes from the current user you can do so by doing the following:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
```

More information can be found [here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)

Comment: Which version of Wordpress are you using? Root Cookie isn't compatible with version higher than 3.3.2

Comment: I suspect that's causing the issues though. Try it without the plugin installed.

Comment: I tried "clear" wordpress, without any plugin, but its not working too.

Comment: Edited my answer, could you check if the above code is working for you?

Comment: Thanks for helping! But it's not working, i get same result(added wordpress to require because wordpress is in that directory), every other function of wordpress is working except this login functionality :/ Did you tried this on your local or some other server?

Comment: This was done on a clean install of Wordpress using MAMP Pro acting as server. My solution is also working with two different directories for wordpress and the api.

Comment: Thanks! For me it's only working if it is in wordpress directory. I think that problem is somewhere in cookies or some server configuration :/ Can you send me your php.ini file?

Comment: I am using the standard settings MAMP Pro rolls out with. Using php 5.5.10